# is it possible to change the collation of one column in a select statement?

Tags: mysql, collation

so i need to change the collation of ONE column from latin1_spanish to latin1_swedish, I found the convert function but can't see how to convert it.

let's say it's column "a"

Answer (score 2):

For a particular query, you can apply a specific collation:

```
SELECT ... WHERE a = b COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

You can change the collation for a column.  Let's say it is currently

```
a VARCHAR(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci
```

by doing

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN a VARCHAR(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can by this:

```
select convert(your_field using latin1) from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
  SELECT your_column COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci FROM your_table;
```